# Change Bottom Navigation Bar selected Item by fab

Tags: flutter

How can I change the Bottom Navigation Bar selected Item in flutter with fab (Floating Action Button)?

It is my fab and I want to change the bottom navigation bar selected item by pressing it.

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: (){


          },)
```

Comment: Using controller??

Comment: yes or no, I'm looking for a good way to solve this problem and if you offer a good way I'll do that. please tell me the best way. with controller or without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) example

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: (){
             _onItemTapped(1);
          },)
```